# OAuth interactions for UWP

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I am following one of Google's blog while changing OAuth,

`https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html?m=1`

The article mentions,

`Google Sign-in and OAuth Examples for Windows, examples
demonstrating how to use the browser to authenticate Google users in various Windows environments such as Universal Windows Platform (UWP), console and desktop apps`

The article does not have link for code samples for Universal Windows Platform (UWP).

Can you please provide link for same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the link to the windows (Console, UWP and WPF) samples https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows.

I got it from here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp